# Compile an INO arduino file into a hex file using c#

Tags: c#, arduino

I am currently writing a c# code that is changing an INO file depending on some parameters the user is chosing in my windows form program. Is there a way to compile the INO file into hex code.

From what I have understood there are many libraries for uploading a hex file to an arduino but I have found none compiling INO code to hex code.

Best Regards 
Victor

Answer (score 0):

No, you need a compiler for that. There are a small handful of C++ compilers, and none of them are written as C# libraries.

However, it is possible to invoke the compiler from your C# application: [arduino-builder](https://github.com/arduino/arduino-builder). Invoke that with the appropriate flags using `Process.Start`.

Comment: Can you give me some help about what i need to learn to do this? I dont really understand how this builder work.

Comment: The README seems fairly clear to me. If you've having a specific problem, then ask a specific question

Comment: Have i understood it right that I will be able to run this process when pressing a specific button in my windows form application? Can i use c# to control this application after running it or do i set the properties and filepaths in some kind of text file before running it. Sorry if I dont understand...

Comment: The README says that it takes its arguments on the command line. So yes, you could launch it from a button on a form. You tell C# to start the application with the right command-line arguments.

Comment: For example.... How do i compile my ino file using the cmd? Can you give me an example?  Thank you!